# Showing text file in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
bb--------->0.918295818426175
mn--------->1.58496250496106
bs--------->1.58496250496106
ddq--------->1.5
gg--------->0.918295818426175
ss--------->0.918295818426175
dd--------->0.918295818426175
vv--------->0.918295818426175
bbw--------->1.5
nn--------->0.918295818426175
sa dfg--------->2.52164068457594
mrg--------->2
ytt--------->1.5
po--------->1.58496250496106
```

this is my text file content i want to show this content in DataGridView 
in below format

```
**bb                   mn                  bs
0.918295818426175   .58496250496106      1.58496250496106**
```

where strings are in column header and values are in rows

How should I do that?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"D:\finatt.txt";
     string[] textdata = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string[] headers = textdata[0].Split(' ');
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    foreach (string header in headers)
    {
        dt1.Columns.Add(header,typeof(string),null);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < textdata.Length; i++)
        dt1.Rows.Add(textdata[i].Split(','));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
}
```

Comment: Provide some code? And why are you using text file?

Comment: Text file contains the data which I want  . That's why I am using text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to process each line one by one, split the column and the value but you need to keep the row values till the end, after all columns are created.

In the below code I use a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and invoke a [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) until a null is returned, indicating the end of the stream.

The processing of each line is done by adding the column name to the [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) while storing the row value till later. I use a simple generic [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for that.

Each line is [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) at a unique character, in this case the `>`. The columnname is obtained by using a [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx). The row value is [TryParsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) as a double. I use the specialized overload to cater for the numeric format.

After all lines are processed all that is left is creating and adding a [NewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx). That row is populated by assigning the array obtained from our values to the [`ItemArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx).

An implementation of above description will look like this:

```
var values = new List<double?>(); // nullable, to handle parse errors

string path = @"D:\finatt.txt";
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{

    string line;

    var lineCount = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lineCount++;
        // line does now have this value
        // bb--------->0.918295818426175
        var split = line.Split('>');
        // in split[0] we now have bb------
        // in split[1] we now have 0.918295818426175
        // find where the - starts
        var startOfDash = split[0].IndexOf('-');
        // so we can get the column name 
        var col = split[0].Substring(0, startOfDash);
        // add that column,
        dt1.Columns.Add(col, typeof(double));
        // store split[1] in the values list to be processed later
        // parse to a double
        double value;
        if (Double.TryParse(split[1],
            NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
            new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." },
            out value))
        {
            values.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            // make sure the values array has the same
            // number of entries as we have columns
            values.Add(null);
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Error on line {0}, for {1} parsing value {2}", lineCount, split[0], split[1]));
        }
    }
}
var row = dt1.NewRow();
dt1.Rows.Add(row);
// assign the values array to the row
// Cast the double the an object in the process.
row.ItemArray = values.Cast<object>().ToArray();

// done all, shows data
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
```